# Determining the size of a basin of attraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, basins-of-attraction

$$\dot x = -2x-y^2$$
$$\dot y = -y-x^2$$

$(0,0)$ is an obvious attractive fixed point, and I'll only look at this one.

I need to get the maximal radius $r > 0$ for a ball centered on the origin so that ball is still included in the basin of attraction.

I used $x^2+y^2$ as my Lyapunov function and determined that its domain of validity, defined by $\dot L < 0$, is given by $ x > -1$ and $y > -2$. But since it is an arbitrary choice I'm not sure I can conclude something from that.

Comment: Well, there is another equilibrium point, so the radius cannot be larger than the distance between the origin and that point.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576408/lyapunov-function-and-an-open-disk-inside-the-basin-of-0-0/3799731#3799731